# sql skipping an insert statement if no results are found

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a number of insert statements like the ones shown below that I am trying to run in one large block. Is there anyway for me to tell the query to skip that particular insert statement and continue on down the list of one of the select statements returns null?

```
    insert into V1144engine.T_edges(edge_id, version, node1_id, node2_id, edge_type_id, created_at, weight,deleted_at) VALUES(V1144ENGINE.S_PK_EDGES.NEXTVAL,0,(Select node_id from V1144engine.T_nodes where node_name = 'Writing an Equation of a Perpendicular Line' and rownum=1),(select node_id from V1144engine.T_nodes where node_name = 'slope'and node_type_id =11),5,SYSDATE,5.318,null);

    insert into V1144engine.T_edges(edge_id, version, node1_id, node2_id, edge_type_id, created_at, weight,deleted_at) VALUES(V1144ENGINE.S_PK_EDGES.NEXTVAL,0,(Select node_id from V1144engine.T_nodes where node_name = 'Writing an Equation of a Perpendicular Line' and rownum=1),(select node_id from V1144engine.T_nodes where node_name = 'vertic'and node_type_id =11),5,SYSDATE,5,null);
```

Comment: When you say one large block, do you mean just a bunch of single insert statements?  If this was a PL/SQL procedure you could use `IF` statement(s), and cursor for loops (if those would be applicable / helpful)

Comment: yes, I do mean a bunch of single insert statements, but it won't be run as a PL/SQL procedure, thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: What program are you using to execute the SQL statements?  SQL*Plus?  SQL Developer?  Something else?  If you're not using a PL/SQL block, that application would control what happens when one statement fails.  The default SQL*Plus and SQL Developer behavior would be to continue with the next statement which sounds like it's the behavior you want.

Comment: I am not executing this with a program, this is for a database build up on a test server, running in sql developer runs fine, but when putting it up on the server it is all wrapped up and either succeeds or fails as a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap it into an `select ... from dual` and restrict on `node1|2_id IS NOT NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO v1144engine.t_edges (edge_id
                                ,version
                                ,node1_id
                                ,node2_id
                                ,edge_type_id
                                ,created_at
                                ,weight
                                ,deleted_at
                                )
 SELECT *
       FROM (
             SELECT 
                    v1144engine.s_pk_edges.NEXTVAL edge_id
                   ,0                              version
                   , (SELECT node1_id
                        FROM v1144engine.t_nodes
                       WHERE node_name = 'Writing an Equation of a Perpendicular Line'
                         AND ROWNUM = 1)           node1_id
                   , (SELECT node_id
                        FROM v1144engine.t_nodes
                       WHERE node_name = 'slope'
                         AND node_type_id = 11)    node2_id
                   ,5       edge_type_id
                   ,SYSDATE                        created_at
                   ,5.318                          weight
                   ,NULL                           deleted_at
               FROM dual
            )
      WHERE node1_id IS NOT NULL
        AND node2_id IS NOT NULL
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could duplicate the predicates of the nested `SELECT`s in `EXISTS` clauses:

```
INSERT INTO v1144engine.t_edges (
    edge_id
,   version
,   node1_id
,   node2_id
,   edge_type_id
,   created_at
,   weight
,   deleted_at
)
SELECT v1144engine.s_pk_edges.NEXTVAL
,      0
,     (SELECT node_id 
       FROM   v1144engine.t_nodes 
       WHERE  node_name = 'Writing an Equation of a Perpendicular Line'
       AND    ROWNUM = 1)
,     (SELECT node_id
       FROM   v1144engine.t_nodes
       WHERE  node_name = 'slope'
       AND    node_type_id = 11)
,      5
,      SYSDATE
,      5.318
,      TO_DATE(NULL)
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT NULL
               FROM   v1144engine.t_nodes 
               WHERE  node_name = 'Writing an Equation of a Perpendicular Line')
AND    EXISTS (SELECT NULL
               FROM   v1144engine.t_nodes
               WHERE  node_name    = 'slope' 
               AND    node_type_id = 11);
```

I don't know how many of these you've got, but, as an alternative, perhaps pivoting like the following would work, as more of a set-based approach?

```
INSERT INTO v1144engine.t_edges (
    edge_id
,   version
,   node1_id
,   node2_id
,   edge_type_id
,   created_at
,   weight
,   deleted_at
)
SELECT v1144engine.s_pk_edges.NEXTVAL
,      0
,      MAX(CASE
           WHEN node_name = 'Writing an Equation of a Perpendicular Line'
           THEN node_id
           END)
,      MAX(CASE
           WHEN node_name = 'slope'
           AND  node_type_id = 11
           THEN node_id
           END)
,      5
,      SYSDATE
,      5.318
,      TO_DATE(NULL)
FROM   v1144engine.t_nodes
WHERE  node_name IN ('Writing an Equation of a Perpendicular Line','slope')
HAVING MAX(CASE
           WHEN node_name = 'Writing an Equation of a Perpendicular Line'
           THEN node_id
           END) IS NOT NULL
AND    MAX(CASE
           WHEN node_name = 'slope'
           AND  node_type_id = 11
           THEN node_id
           END) IS NOT NULL
;
```

(Warning:  untested code.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the selects into a temporary table and then generate the dynamic SQL from that?

Comment: because all of our node_id's are generated from sequences which are different on each machine, so it has to do the select from within this insert statement, a static ID won't work.

Comment: You could put the statements into a table and loop thru using a cursor checking the row count as you go. If the row count isn't incremented after the insert, you know it has failed.

Comment: alright, so that works, but it's still very tedious, since I'm adding update and insert statements, when I find an error I still have to manually remove it. Any ideas on how to get around that?

Comment: If you want to track what inserts fail, just create another column which you update with success or failure.

Comment: Doesn't really help the fact that I would actually have to remove them manually, but thank you.

Comment: There is nothing to stop you putting this in a transaction and writing out which ones failed...